# How to validate required validation for input type file in vee validate 3.0 version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
        <ValidationProvider name='file' rules="required">

            <div slot-scope="{ errors }">

            <input id="file" ref="file" type="file" placeholder="Upload file" class="form-control" name="file"/>

               <span class="required-field">{{ errors[0]}}</span>

            </div>

        </ValidationProvider>
```

only file validation not work proper else input type text fire and work proper after filling value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Pleas use example code for required file

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ validate, errors }" name="file" vid="file" rules="required">
    <input ref="fileFormCatSupOne" type='file' class="hidden" accept="image/*" @change="onChangeFile($event) || validate($event)"/>
    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic mb-3">{{errors[0]}}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Answer (score -1):

How did you upgrade to vue 3.0 when  it hasn't been released yet?

Comment: sorry vee validate package.